# insertion amount of a newly created product

Tags: php, model-view-controller, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm creating a product on prestashop, I enter the amount with this function:

```
echo "1";
StockAvailable::setQuantity($id_prod, 0, $quantity,1);
echo "2";
```

the result is:

```
1fatal error
```

going on the backend, the product is and the amount set correctly.
How can I avoid the "fatal error"?
Report me error here: classes/Product.php in line 2582: if (!$id_cart && !isset($context->employee)) die(Tools::displayError());

This code is in the function "getPriceStatic". It is normal that it is pulled to perform "StockAvailable::setQuantity"?

I have not changed classes and I do not override

Comment: Hello. Active DEBUG MODE in Prestashop. This will tell you what is de exactly problem that causes the fatal error. Good luck.

Comment: It is active, but not from any notification

Comment: Are you developing in local or on server?

Comment: i developing in server

Comment: Which version of PS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually I use this snippet (adapt it to your needs):

```
$shop_is_feature_active = Shop::isFeatureActive();
$shops = Shop::getContextListShopID();
if ($shop_is_feature_active) {
    foreach ($shops as $shop) {
        StockAvailable::setQuantity((int)$product->id, 0, (int)$product->quantity, (int)$shop);
    }
} else {
    StockAvailable::setQuantity((int)$product->id, 0, (int)$product->quantity, (int)$this->context->shop->id);
}
```

However, I always suggest to check if the product is in that shop.

It is important to check if

```
Context::getContext()->employee
```

is not empty, otherwise enter:

```
$psContext = Context::getContext();
if (!$psContext->employee) {
    $psContext->employee = new Employee(PS_DEFAULT_EMPLOYEE);
}
```

Comment: i developing in server. sempre "fatal error". Always "fatal error". Log in "else" and error. In the backend the quantity is updated

Comment: Mmm... it's strange... Check server configuration to display errors, the string `fatal error` doesn't exist either in classes or controllers

Comment: Report me error here: classes/Product.php in line 2582: if (!$id_cart && !isset($context->employee)) die(Tools::displayError());

Comment: this code is in the function "getPriceStatic". It is normal that it is pulled to perform "StockAvailable::setQuantity"?

Comment: I solved it by entering what you have written to me. And at the beginning of the file I added:
    $psContext = Context::getContext();
    if (!$psContext->employee) {
        $psContext->employee = new Employee(PS_DEFAULT_EMPLOYEE);
    }

Comment: Mmm... Never checked the employee in my imports. I guess you have some modules hooked on this hook `actionUpdateQuantity` and make some operations with product price, so to answer to your question 'it is normal that it is pulled...' the answer is no :)